# What is ReplayAll() and VerifyAll() in RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

```
[Test]
public void MockAGenericInterface()
{
    MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
    IList<int> list = mocks.Create Mock<IList<int>>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(list);
    Expect.Call(list.Count).Return(5);
    mocks.ReplayAll();
    Assert.AreEqual(5, list.Count); 
    mocks.VerifyAll();
}
```

What is the purpose of `ReplayAll()` and `VerifyAll()` in this code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The code snippet demonstrates the **Record/Replay/Verify** syntax of Rhino.Mocks. You first record the expectations for a mock (using `Expect.Call()`, then you call `ReplayAll()` to run the mock simulation. Then, you call `VerifyAll()` to verify that all the expectations have been met.

This is an obsolete syntax, by the way. The new syntax is called [**AAA Syntax - Arrange, Act, Assert**](http://svengrand.blogspot.com/2011/02/rhino-mocks-arange-act-assert-aaa.html) and is usually easier to work with than the old R/R/V one. You code snipped translated to AAA:

```
  [Test]
  public void MockAGenericInterface()
  {
    IList<int> list = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IList<int>>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(list);
    list.Expect (x => x.Count).Return(5);
    Assert.AreEqual(5, list.Count); 
    list.VerifyAllExpectations();
  }
```